# Docker volume not mounting on Windows

Tags: windows, nginx, docker, virtualbox, mounted-volumes

Already added my workspace (W:\) drive to Shared folders, but can't mount it as volume on Docker containers.

[image]

Any tips?

Comment: Are you sure it's failing to mount it as a volume? I'd have thought if the location was missing, you'd get a 404 Not Found error rather than a 403 Forbidden. If you run a bash shell inside the running container, can you see and navigate to the mapped volume?

Comment: Take a look. First `ls` at `/w/docker/` shows `index.html`, but `docker exec ls` returns nothing.

Comment: hi @LeoCavalcante, i am facing the same issue too. May i know whether you got the solution for this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @davidlee - I didn't​ found any solutions for this issue. I moved my workspace to a folder inside my home dir.